# Eclipse Editor Custom Color

Tags: eclipse, colors

[image]

In my Eclipse IDE Indigo Release, the color for matching brackets is not set properly, I can't see the text of the tag "`<div class=...>`" in the bracket, so I want to change it, there is an "Eclipse_Theme.epf" file that I imported into Eclipse to set the custom colors, I've used the following approach before to change the colors I want to replace :

```
[1] Take a screen shot of the Eclipse editor
[2] Paste the screen into a window's painter program
[3] Use the color picker to pick the color I want to change
[4] Find it's RGB values, e.g. 10,20,255
[5] In "Eclipse_Theme.epf" search for the RBG value and replace them with my new RGB choice, save the file
[6] Import "Eclipse_Theme.epf" into Eclipse again to replace the old one, and the new color will show up in my Eclipse editor.
```

But some how the above approach didn't work for the above problem, the color for matching brackets is not found in the "Eclipse_Theme.epf" file, my question is , where is it in Eclipse, that I can change this color, or which property in the "Eclipse_Theme.epf" file that represents this color, why is it not found ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Window->Preferences->Web->HTML->Editor->Syntax Coloring, or something similar, depending on the technology you use (JSF, HTML etc.). Another possibility is Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations

Comment: Yes, the exact path is : Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations->Matching Tags

Comment: @Frank Do you maybe know if it's somehow possible to change the colors of all 'external' (imported) tags within a JSP-page (like e.g. JSTL tags <c:if>, <c:***>).

Comment: Or maybe @Dr.Nefario knows?

Comment: @LowLevel Sorry, I haven't used Eclipse for 2 years now and JSP pages are legacy for me :D